# Парсинг сайтов с AJAX на python

Tags: python, ajax, парсер

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно распарсить сайт, но проблема в том, что почти все данные подгружаются при помощи AJAX кнопкой "показать еще". Подскажите, как можно реализовать и решить данную проблему?